# ORA-00917: missing comma ON INSERT

Tags: oracle

I am getting missing comma error for insert Query.Following is the table structure.
SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6e49/3

I think I am missing something little but I am unable to identify it.

```
CREATE TABLE OAS_INFORMATIONMANAGEMENT
(
 ID              NUMBER,
 EMPLOYEENO      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 EMPLOYEENAME    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
 DESIGNATION     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 LINEMANAGER     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 REOPRTINGTO     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DEPARTMENT      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DOJ             DATE,
 REGION          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 LOCATION        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
 EMPLOYMENTTYPE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 COMPANY         VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 GENDER          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DOB             DATE,
 CNIC            NUMBER,
 MOBILENO        NUMBER,
 EMAIL           VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DEGREE          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 MAJORSUBJECT    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 KPI_AMOUNT      NUMBER,
 SALARY          NUMBER,
 EOBI            NUMBER,
 CITY            VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DATADATE        DATE,
 USERNAME        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 STATUS          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 JOB_STATUS      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
 );

insert into OAS_INFORMATIONMANAGEMENT(EMPLOYEENO, EMPLOYEENAME, DESIGNATION,
      LINEMANAGER, REOPRTINGTO, DEPARTMENT, DOJ, REGION, LOCATION,
      EMPLOYMENTTYPE, COMPANY, GENDER, DOB, CNIC, MOBILENO, EMAIL, DEGREE,
      SALARY, EOBI,DATADATE, USERNAME,CITY,STATUS,KPI_AMOUNT
      VALUES('UHRS/TEST2','tahir','Admin Assistant','aamir.ullah-uhrs',
      'aamir.ullah-uhrs','Security','22-Nov-2014','HQ','ISLAMABAD',
      'Contractual','UHRS','Male','22-Nov-2014',3840159388649,3124455667,
      'mkmohsinali@gmail.com','Secondary',23456,456,SYSDATE,'zahid.ali','Abbottabad',
      'Y',344);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket after: `KPI_AMOUNT`